# error while installing any of npm module

Tags: node.js, npm

i am trying to install a async module in my system, it is giving following error.
and this error is coming all the modules i am trying to install. please give me ideas to solve this problem. it has become bottle neck.

```
C:\Windows>npm install async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.eu/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.eu/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.eu/async
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "async"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Looks to me like a bad internet connection or npm was down.

Comment: @Manu : Have you found the answer of your problem? I am also getting the same error. Do you have the solution..